# Some examples of what lacan calls 'subject'

Tags: psychoanalysis, subjectivity, lacan

I've been searching to find some examples of 'subject' in psychoanalysis of lacan and i can't find good examples of 'subject of enunciation' and 'subject of enunciated'. Can someone please give some good examples so that i can better understand the idea?

Answer (score 1):

Lacans approach is well described on [this website](http://www.iep.utm.edu/lacweb/) 
 There, you can find the following statement on your question:

> Lacan's distinction between the subject of the enunciated and the
> subject of the enunciated can be exposed further through examining his
> treatment of the liar paradox. This is the paradox of someone saying:
> "I am a liar." The paradox is that, if we suppose the proposition true
> ("person x is a liar"), we at the same time then have no reason to
> believe he is telling the truth when he says: "I am a liar." As a
> liar, he can only be lying when he says this. But what this means is
> that we must suppose that he is a sincere truth-telling person. Lacan
> argues that this is a paradox only insofar as we have wrongly
> collapsed the distinction between the subject enunciated in the
> sentence, and the subject of the enunciation. A better understanding
> of the meaning of this utterance can be garnered by presenting the
> speech-act in both its two dimensions, as a case wherein (to
> formalize): person x says: "I am a liar." The point is that the "I" in
> the spoken sentence here is what Lacan calls "the subject of the
> enunciated." Of this ego, it may (or may not) be true that s/he is a
> liar. Yet, this ego is in no way to be identified with what we have
> called "person x" in the above formalization. "Person x" here is not
> the subject spoken about. S/he is the person speaking. And Lacan's
> point is that it this subject of the enunciation that addresses itself
> to the Other supposed to know in analysis, despite whatever egoic
> plays and ploys the analysand might masquerade before his/her analyst
> in what s/he enunciates.

The liar example above and the later example on *"I am not where I think"* might be of help for you.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is one of the most confusing concepts in Lacanian writings.

At the most fundamental level, it is the human mind. However, it is not a clear and distinct Cartesian cogito with an ego, it is Freudian subconsciousness with some Hegelian, Saussurean and Heideggerian elements mixed in.

Here is the best and the clearest definition of the subject as per Lacan: to be a subject is to be a subject to...

Subject is always "subject to" something. To the Symbolic, to the master signifier, to psychoses, to neuroses etc. Human beings are always passively subjected by those things.

Answer (score 0):

The subject is a *méconnaisance* or a misrecognition.

Take the example of someone saying: "I am thinking about myself".

Where is the subject? Which is it? Is it the "I" who is doing the thinking? Or is it the "myself" which is being reflexively posited as an object-subject?

Or is it the person actually speaking the sentence?

In any case, the subject of the enunciated is the subject of the clause. The "I" is the subject in this sentence, the grammatical subject. The subject of the enunciation is the person actually speaking the sentence.

But if that person is yourself talking to yourself, then where do you locate the "I"? As soon as you think about yourself you're projecting yourself as an object in front of yourself. That's not the subject though, just a reflection of it.

You can actually never articulate yourself as a thinking subject. As soon as you try, you're projecting yourself as an object. The "I" actually doing the thinking, the projecting disappears as soon as you direct your gaze towards it.

It's like looking at your own face. It's impossible to do. You can only ever assume it exists. You can only ever see a reflection of it in a mirror or an impression in a photograph or video. A reproduction. The original is forever hidden from you.

The subject is even more elusive than one's face though. Maybe it's your awareness of the world around you, but where exactly is this awareness located? Your awareness is found not inside your head but properly in the place of whatever you're focussing on. If I focus on the clock on the wall, there is my awareness, if I focus on the birds in the garden outside, there's my awareness. If I focus on myself being aware of the birds in the garden, again the subject disappears and just an objective reflection remains.

The subject of the enunciated can be apprehended as the signifiers of the enunciation. The subject of the enunciation however disappears into nothingness as soon as the gaze is directed towards it. And yet we are utterly convinced that as Descartes said: "I think therefore I am".

The ultimate*méconnaisance* according to Lacan.